# ModelState.IsValid em cadastro dentro de modal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp

Estou utilizando um formulário de cadastro dentro de um `modal`, entretanto quando a condição do `ModelState.IsValid` não é satisfeita a `view` é retornada. Só que ao invés de retornar a mesma `view` antes da ação de submissão do forma, ela volta totalmente desconfigurada, contendo apenas a `view` de cadastro. Segue o código da `view` de cadastro:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Cadastrar(Pessoa pessoa)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //código caso seja válido
    }
    return View(pessoa);
}
```

Como proceder para exibição dos erros na `view` para o usuário?

Answer (score 1):

Colega, como você esta chamando esta View, geralmente quando criamos modal fazemos por ajax e alteramos somente parte do código e o return da View geralmente é feito como

```
return PartialView(Pessoa)
```

Aconselho a tratar todos os erros em uma função JavaScript interceptando o Submit do form.

Seu Form

```
    <form id="FormCadastro" action="~/Alunos/Cadastro" method="post" class="form-horizontal form-enter-cancel" onsubmit="FormSubmit(this); return false;">
```

exemplo de funcão Submit

```
 function FormSubmit(frm) {

    var erros = 0;
    var mErro = '';

    if (frm.idMovimentacao.value == 0) {
        erros++;
        erroValidacao("idMovimentacao", "Selecione o tipo de Movimentação");
        frm.idMovimentacao.focus();
    }

    if (frm.idSituacao.value == 0) {
        erros++;
        erroValidacao("idSituacao", "Selecione a situação");
        frm.idSituacao.focus();
    }

    if (erros > 0) {
        if (mErro != '') {
            MensagemTexto(mErro);
        }
        return false;
    }

    if ($("#FormCadastro").valid() == false) {
            erros++;
    }

    if (erros > 0) {
            return false;
    }
    else {
          frm.submit();
    }

};
```

[Código Expresso](http://www.codigoexpresso.com.br)